# Unable to use usdt token inside contract

Tags: smart-contract

I have a contract that works with usdt. It creates an IERC20 object of the contract address that we pass to it in constructor, but the contract is working abnormally when I try to call usdt.transferFrom function. Here's the whole error trace (hardhat testing).

Here's the function that is causing this error

> function deposit(uint256 depositAmount) external {
>
> ```
>     if (isDiscounted) {
>         usdt.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), depositAmount.mul(9).div(10));        
>     }
>     else {
>         usdt.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), depositAmount);
>     }
>     _deposit(msg.sender, depositAmount);
>     uint256 contractBalance = usdt.balanceOf(address(this));
>     if (contractBalance >= maxContractBalance) {
>         maxContractBalance = contractBalance;
>         
>         if (isFrozen) {
>             isFrozen = false;
>         }
>     }
>     emit Deposit(msg.sender, depositAmount);
> }
> ```

```
    EVENT TetherToken.Approval(owner=0xd5b7517b5aDE4CD7d90DBdb612379C771e0592FF, spender=0x59b670e9fA9D0A427751Af201D676719a970857b, value=2000000000)
CALL TetherToken.approve(_spender=0x59b670e9fA9D0A427751Af201D676719a970857b, _value=2000000000)
   EVENT TetherToken.Approval(owner=0x8eE57D6Aa734663b91f06246a478F41beC8E78Ee, spender=0x59b670e9fA9D0A427751Af201D676719a970857b, value=2000000000)
CALL TetherToken.approve(_spender=0x59b670e9fA9D0A427751Af201D676719a970857b, _value=2000000000)
   EVENT TetherToken.Approval(owner=0x2315843F9fC72ce897D83984274676304FCfdc11, spender=0x59b670e9fA9D0A427751Af201D676719a970857b, value=2000000000)
CALL TetherToken.approve(_spender=0x59b670e9fA9D0A427751Af201D676719a970857b, _value=2000000000)
   EVENT TetherToken.Approval(owner=0xf5506aBcE02b5BcFF90f007E1c4E3D5b2512FB55, spender=0x59b670e9fA9D0A427751Af201D676719a970857b, value=2000000000)
CALL TetherToken.approve(_spender=0x59b670e9fA9D0A427751Af201D676719a970857b, _value=2000000000)
   EVENT TetherToken.Approval(owner=0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266, spender=0x59b670e9fA9D0A427751Af201D676719a970857b, value=2000000000)
CALL TwoXWorld.register(referral=0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266)
   EVENT TwoXWorld.Register(user=0x30178B75fBa2267De822b61d9026b6e9EafCC181, referral=0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266)
CALL TwoXWorld.deposit(depositAmount=100000000)
   CALL TetherToken.transferFrom(_from=0x30178B75fBa2267De822b61d9026b6e9EafCC181, _to=0x59b670e9fA9D0A427751Af201D676719a970857b, _value=90000000)
      EVENT TetherToken.Transfer(from=0x30178B75fBa2267De822b61d9026b6e9EafCC181, to=0x59b670e9fA9D0A427751Af201D676719a970857b, value=90000000)
   REVERT UnknownError(0x)

      1) Should allow users to make deposits


  0 passing (6s)
  1 failing

  1) 2xWorld
       Deposit
         Should allow users to make deposits:
     Error: Transaction reverted without a reason string
      at <UnrecognizedContract>.<unknown> (0x59b670e9fa9d0a427751af201d676719a970857b)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
      at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:64:3)
      at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:533:9)
      at processTimers (node:internal/timers:507:7)
      at async HardhatNode._mineBlockWithPendingTxs (node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\hardhat-network\provider\node.ts:1815:23)
      at async HardhatNode.mineBlock (node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\hardhat-network\provider\node.ts:504:16)
      at async EthModule._sendTransactionAndReturnHash (node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\hardhat-network\provider\modules\eth.ts:1522:18)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that the error is caused by the fact that USDT doesn't follow the ERC20 standard (the function `transferFrom` doesn't return true/false).

What you can try to do is make an interface for it:

```
interface IERC20_USDT {
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint value) external;
}
```

and write your code like this:

```
IERC20_USDT(address(usdt)).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), depositAmount);
```

---

An alternative solution is implementing the "SafeERC20" library by Openzeppelin. See [this discussion](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/106894/noob-question-about-how-to-use-safeerc20-sol-from-openzeppelin) for example.

Comment: Thanks, it helped. Also the contract that I am writing is to be deployed on polygon and polygon's USDT contract uses a proxy method. The smart contract is working perfectly with polygon's USDT contract.

Answer (score 1):

For every token to send funds via any app, we(owner) of the sender account should give allowance to the receiver account, if this is not done then the transaction would fail for sure.

Answer (score 0):

As an EOA the msg.sender approved the smart contract to move tokens? If not you should introduce the approve/allowance to smart contract.

Comment: The msg.sender has approved the tokens. The smart contract works just fine with basic ERC20 token, but throws this error when testing with actual usdt source code

Comment: try this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67511692/how-to-receive-and-send-usdt-in-a-smart-contract

Answer (score 0):

The USDT contract on Ethereum doesn't return a boolean in functions like transfer, transferFrom, and approve. Other blockchains fixed this issue with USDT, it happens on Ethereum as far as I know, the solution is to use the library safeERC20.